# Nginx - too many redirect

Tags: nginx

I'm using cdn subdomain.
The files are now available at cdn.website.com/uploads/*.(img|png|zip|..).

The old URL structure is cdn.website.com/*.(img|png|zip|..).

This code works fine;

```
 location ~* ^/.+\.(png|jpg|doc|gif|html|jpeg|zip|rar)$ {
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://cdn.website.com/uploads/$1 permanent;
 }
```

Routing from the main directory to the "uploads" directory is working properly. 
But when I open a file on the uploads array, it replicates the "uploads" directory.
Example;

cdn.website.com/uploads/x1.jpg

cdn.website.com/uploads/uploads/x1.jpg

cdn.website.com/uploads/uploads//uploads/x1.jpg

...

Many redirect problem.

How to fix this problem?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location pattern needs to be narrowed down.

```
location ~* ^/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.(png|jpg|doc|gif|html|jpeg|zip|rar)$ {
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://cdn.website.com/uploads/$1 permanent;
}
```

Match requests that start with / and contain any of the following characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ or - and end with .png, .jpg, .doc, .gif, .html, .jpeg, .zip and .rar. This excludes requests within a sub directory.

Also, haven't tested the regex pattern but that *should* work.